Gmsh - flow in the channel with obstacle
I need some help with this mesh. I want to make sure that the internal part of the circle is not filled by the triangles of the mesh. How can I modify the code below to achieve this?
Mesh.MshFileVersion = 2.2;
// Definir o tamanho da malha lc = 0.25;
// Definir os pontos do retângulo Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, lc}; Point(2) = {8, 0, 0, lc}; Point(3) = {8, 2, 0, lc}; Point(4) = {0, 2, 0, lc};
// Definir os pontos do círculo (obstáculo) xc = 4; // Coordenada x do centro do círculo yc = 1; // Coordenada y do centro do círculo r = 0.2; // Raio do círculo
// Definir pontos ao redor do círculo Point(5) = {xc, yc + r, 0, lc}; // Ponto superior Point(6) = {xc, yc, 0, lc}; // Ponto central Point(7) = {xc, yc -r, 0, lc}; // Ponto inferior
// Definir as linhas do retângulo Line(1) = {1, 2}; Line(2) = {2, 3}; Line(3) = {3, 4}; Line(4) = {4, 1};
// Definir o círculo (completo) Circle(5) = {7, 6, 5}; // Primeiro metade do círculo Circle(6) = {5, 6, 7}; // Segundo metade do círculo
// Criar a superfície do retângulo Curve Loop(1) = {1, 2, 3, 4}; Plane Surface(1) = {1};
// Criar a superfície do círculo Curve Loop(2) = {5, 6, 7}; Plane Surface(2) = {2};
// Subtrair o círculo do retângulo BooleanDifference { Surface{1}; Delete; } { Surface{2}; Delete; };
// Configurar a malha Transfinite Surface {1};
I want to make sure that the internal part of the circle is not filled by the triangles of the mesh
